# Redirecting using Apache Mod Rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I edited the file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

and added

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \ [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

I am using local server hosting wifi
I want to redirect all requests to the /var/www/html/index.html webpage

it redirects some requests like example.com but the problem is: it does not redirect example.com/something and also does not redirect https://example.com